# onBindViewHolder position is starting again at 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Using recyclerview and first initialising the listview it begins to go through each item 1,2,3,4,5 but then suddenly the position value reverts back to 0 and getting the text values from the data items already used., thus my data in the list is looping, to look like:

0,1,2,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5

I'm using a ViewHolder, i'm using the position that comes from the ViewHolder, when debugging the items list size is constant and the values correct. Everything seems correctly implemented yet, i presume it's recycling values or something? Before i've even scrolled or tapped anything.

```
public class AnswerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnswerAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {
List<NumberItem> items;
private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

public AnswerAdapter() {
    setHasStableIds(true);
    SparseBooleanArray localSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.selectedItems = localSparseBooleanArray;
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
    this.items = localArrayList;
    this.items.addAll(AnswerListContent.ITEMS);
}

public void clearSelections() {
    this.selectedItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

public NumberItem getItem(int pos) {
    return this.items.get(pos);
}

public int getSelectedItemCount() {
    return this.selectedItems.size();
}

public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList(this.selectedItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < this.selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        localArrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(this.selectedItems.keyAt(i)));
    }
    return localArrayList;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder paramNumberViewHolder, int paramInt) {
    NumberItem localNumberItem = items.get(paramNumberViewHolder.getPosition());
    paramNumberViewHolder.text.setText(localNumberItem.num.toString());
    if (this.selectedItems.get(paramInt, false)) {
        paramNumberViewHolder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_bg_selected);
    } else {
        paramNumberViewHolder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_bg);
    }
}

public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup paramViewGroup, int paramInt) {
    View localView = LayoutInflater.from(paramViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_answer, paramViewGroup, false);
    NumberViewHolder localNumberViewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(localView);
    return localNumberViewHolder;
}

public void removeItem(int paramInt) {
    this.items.remove(paramInt);
}

public void swapPositions(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    Collections.swap(this.items, paramInt1, paramInt2);
}

public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
    if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
        selectedItems.delete(pos);
    } else {
        selectedItems.put(pos, true);
    }
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
}

public final static class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text;

    public NumberViewHolder(View localView) {
        super(localView);
        this.text = ((TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.title));
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved! For the help of anyone who comes across this issue also, the problem was:

```
setHasStableIds(true);
```

Which I set in the constructor.

It turns out I originally had overridden 'getItemID' ( Which would have allowed the list to work ) however I later removed it in favour of a different approach and FORGOT to remove the aforementioned hasStableId's!

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to onBind is the position that you should bind.

`paramInt = position`

so you should be calling 
`items.get(position);`
not
`items.get(paramNumberViewHolder.getPosition());`

You are probably receiving a stale position. ViewHolder#getPosition is valid for ViewHolders which are already bound.

Comment: Works exactly the same. I actually read that in a RecyclerView you should get the position from the viewholder anyway due to the fact the RC does not rebind every view, only those that changed.

Comment: Yep but that is valid for up to date view holders. (click callbacks etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
```

Helped me resolve this issue.